# Difference results between python and R, mean and covariance

Tags: python, r

I was trying to rewrite a code from python to R but I am finding some difficulties and some inconsistencies when I compare the results with python.

I have 3 files that can be found here:

https://pastebin.com/jWCLWKzi  -->  btc.csv

https://pastebin.com/53Hi2XsT  -->  eth.csv

https://pastebin.com/xiXtvVwH  -->  ltc.csv

In R I do the following:

```
library(dplyr)

# simply read the file and keep the appropriate columns
get_crypto_series=function(a_name){
  df_val=read.csv(paste0(a_name,".csv"))
  df_val=df_val[, c("date", "PriceUSD") ]
  return(df_val)
}

# join dataframe by date filling with NA if a date is missing
join_series=function(a_list_crypto, a_names){
  a_join=a_list_crypto[[1]]
  for(i in 2:length(a_list_crypto)){
    a_join=left_join(a_join, a_list_crypto[[i]], by="date")
  }
  colnames(a_join)[2:ncol(a_join)]=a_names
  rownames(a_join)=a_join[,1]
  a_join=a_join[, 2:ncol(a_join)]
  return(a_join)
}

# evaluate the daily return, that is day_X/day_(X-1)  -  1
# it should give the same results as the python pct_change
a_return=function(a_join){
  a_cnames=colnames(a_join)
  a_cnames=paste0("return_", a_cnames)
  ancol=ncol(a_join)
  for(i in 1:ancol){
    c_vals=as.numeric(a_join[,i])
    tvals=sapply(1:length(c_vals), function(x, c_vals){
      if(x==1){
        return(NA)
      }
      else{
        return(c_vals[x]/c_vals[x-1] - 1)
      }
    }, c_vals=c_vals )
    a_join[,a_cnames[i]]= tvals
  }
  return(a_join)
}


a_name_assets=c("btc", "eth", "ltc")
a_list=list()
for(i in a_name_assets){
  asset_vals=get_crypto_series(i)
  a_list[[i]]=asset_vals  
}

all_assets=join_series(a_list, paste0(a_name_assets, "_inUSD"))
all_assets=a_return(all_assets)

mean_daily_returns=colMeans(all_assets[, grepl("return_", colnames(all_assets))], na.rm = TRUE )
cov_matrix=cov(all_assets[ ,grepl("return_", colnames(all_assets))], use="complete.obs")
```

Now, when I print mean_daily_return in R I get:

```
return_btc_inUSD return_eth_inUSD return_ltc_inUSD 
     0.003504832      0.004627466      0.002743313
```

and cov_matrix in R:

```
                 return_btc_inUSD return_eth_inUSD return_ltc_inUSD
return_btc_inUSD      0.001703876      0.001491297      0.001605524
return_eth_inUSD      0.001491297      0.003185715      0.002137277
return_ltc_inUSD      0.001605524      0.002137277      0.003877886
```

In python I do something similar:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

def read_crypto_asset(a_name):
    a_asset=pd.read_csv('{}.csv'.format(a_name))
    a_asset['date']= pd.to_datetime(a_asset['date'])
    a_asset=a_asset[["date","PriceUSD"]]
    return a_asset

def merge_list_assets(a_list, assets_names):
    merge=a_list[0]
    for i in range(1, len(a_list)):
        merge=pd.merge(merge,a_list[i], how='inner', on=["date"])
        
    merge["date"]=merge["date"].astype(object)
    merge["date"] = merge.date.dt.date
    merge.reset_index()
    merge.index = merge.date
    merge=merge.iloc[:,1:]
    assets_names=[i+"_inUSD" for i in assets_names ]
    merge.columns=assets_names
    return(merge)

assets=["btc", "eth", "ltc"]
list_asset=[]
for i in assets:
    list_asset.append(read_crypto_asset(i))

data=merge_list_assets(list_asset, assets)

#obtain the daily returns
returns = data.pct_change()
mean_daily_returns = returns.mean()
cov_matrix = returns.cov()
```

If I print mean_daily_returns in python I get:

```
btc_inUSD    0.003370
eth_inUSD    0.005638
ltc_inUSD    0.003449
dtype: float64
```

and cov_matrix in python:

```
    btc_inUSD   eth_inUSD   ltc_inUSD
btc_inUSD   0.001577    0.001288    0.001481
eth_inUSD   0.001288    0.004159    0.001807
ltc_inUSD   0.001481    0.001807    0.003425
```

These results are quite different.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I'd strongly suggest making a **minimal** example. With over thousands of rows of data, you can't check either result easily. Reduce your data to 5-10 rows and you should be able to easily check each step and then you know which implementation is right and which has a bug.

Comment: I will say the R code is pretty poor, not using vectorization will be inefficient, and makes the code much longer than it needs to be. Does it need to be base R or would you be open to `dplyr` or `data.table` solutions? I guess it's using `left_join`, so is already using a little bit of `dplyr`...

Comment: @GregorThomas optimization is not a problem right now since I am working with relatively small files and it's not a professional project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem.

The difference comes from the behavior of

```
colMeans(all_assets[, grepl("return_", colnames(all_assets))], na.rm = TRUE )
```

and:

```
returns.mean()
```

What python is doing is to reduce the columns to the complete cases and then calculate the mean and the covariance.
To perform the same operation in R that python is doing one should find the complete cases and then use them in colMeans, like as follow:

```
t_assets=all_assets[, grepl("return_", colnames(all_assets))]
t_assets=t_assets[complete.cases(t_assets),]
mean_daily_returns=colMeans(t_assets, na.rm = TRUE )
cov_matrix=cov(t_assets, use="complete.obs")
```

The latter gives results that are almost the same (but at this point I think there are some truncation somewhere) as python:

```
return_btc_inUSD return_eth_inUSD return_ltc_inUSD 
     0.003431730      0.005638465      0.003542157
```